# Failed to instantiate module in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I am new to AngularJS and I am trying to set up angularjs routing together with a flask service but it doesn't seem to work. Here you can see the error I am getting when I run the application:

> Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.25/$injector modulerr?p0=scotchApp&p1=%5B%24injector%3Aunpr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.25%2F%24injector%2Funpr%3Fp0%3D%2524routeProvider%0AD%2F%3C%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.25%2Fangular.min.js%3A6%3A450%0Agc%2Fl.%24injector%3C%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.25%2Fangular.min.js%3A36%3A202%0Ac%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.25%2Fangular.min.js%3A34%3A305%0Ad%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.25%2Fangular.min.js%3A35%3A1%0Ae%2F%3C%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.25%2Fangular.min.js%3A33%3A386%0Ar%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.25%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A288%0Ae%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.25%2Fangular.min.js%3A33%3A207%0Agc%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.25%2Fangular.min.js%3A36%3A309%0Afc%2Fc%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.25%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A170%0Afc%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.25%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A387%0AXc%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.25%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A415%0A%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.25%2Fangular.min.js%3A214%3A469%0Aa%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.25%2Fangular.min.js%3A145%3A67%0Aoe%2Fc%2F%3C%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.25%2Fangular.min.js%3A31%3A223%0Ar%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.25%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A288%0Aoe%2Fc%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.25%2Fangular.min.js%3A31%3A207%0A

Here is my project structure:

```
 angular_routing/
      flask_service.py
      static/
        script.js
      templates/
        index.html
        ....
```

This is my `script.js` file:

```
var scotchApp = angular.module('scotchApp', [""]);
    // configure our routes
    scotchApp.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider

            // route for the home page
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl : 'templates/home.html',
                controller  : 'mainController'
            })

            // route for the about page
            .when('/about', {
                templateUrl : 'templates/about.html',
                controller  : 'aboutController'
            })

            // route for the contact page
            .when('/contact', {
                templateUrl : 'templates/contact.html',
                controller  : 'contactController'
            });

            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });

    // create the controller and inject Angular's $scope
    scotchApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
        // create a message to display in our view
        $scope.message = 'Everyone come and see how good I look!';
    });

    scotchApp.controller('aboutController', function($scope) {
        $scope.message = 'Look! I am an about page.';
    });

    scotchApp.controller('contactController', function($scope) {
        $scope.message = 'Contact us! JK. This is just a demo.';
    });
```

This is my `index.html` file:

```
<html ng-app="scotchApp">
<head>
    <title>
        Hello world!
    </title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>

    <script src="static/script.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-controller="mainController">

        <!-- HEADER AND NAVBAR -->
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Angular Routing Example</a>
                </div>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i> About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <!-- MAIN CONTENT AND INJECTED VIEWS -->
        <div id="main">
            <!-- angular templating -->
            <!-- this is where content will be injected -->
            <div ng-view></div>

        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Finally, this is my `flask_service.py` file:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `var scotchApp = angular.module('scotchApp', ['ngRoute']);` instead of `var scotchApp = angular.module('scotchApp', [""]);`, otherwise you will fail to instantiate the module.

Read more about [AngularJS modules](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module).

Comment: hey it finally worked... I remember putting 'ngRoute' as a dependency before but it didn't work then.

Comment: now there is a different problem.. the routing cannot find the templates in the templates folder

Comment: once I've got 15 reputation, my vote would appear :) thank your for you help

Comment: btw, the prefixing doesn't solve the problem with the routing

Comment: Please take a look at the [Stack Overflow Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and post a new question with a [complete, minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).